# How to implement Hashtags using Redis database

Tags: redis, hashtag

I am working on an application which needs # hashtags feature using REDIS as the database.
Current implementation:

- Key: *Post_Hashtag_Id* Value: `STRING` of hashtag names separated by spaces
- Key: *Hashtags* Value: `SORTED SET` of hashtag names with SCORE as current count of posts per hashtag. Using [ZINCRBY](https://redis.io/commands/zincrby) to increase score when new post gets added with same hashtag.

Currently, this works but soon need to implement **trending** hashtags on basis of posts counts over a particular time. So current `SORTED SET` SCORE also needs to consider time factor.

How can I better implement this hashtag feature? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you consider using timeseries to collect the events by time?

Comment: @GuyKorland Currently, only collecting created timestamp when a new post is made.

Comment: You might want to checkthr RedisTimeSeries module

Comment: @GuyKorland Checking it thanks. Any suggestions to improve on my current hashtag design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current sorted set stores the total count per hash tag. You can perform the same `ZINCRBY` on an additional key with a name that reflects a period, e.g. "hashtags:20201209" to denote today. To show the trending tags, you can `ZRANGE` on that key.

Comment: If I understand correct you suggesting hashtags:20201209 will have score as number of hash tag today and value as hashtag name?

Comment: That's the basic idea, yep.